# Problema Nextval Postgres Delphi

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Estou fazendo uma aplicação, no qual preciso incrementar uma *sequence* e verificar se aquele valor já foi usado em outra tabela, pois caso já tenha sido devo ignorar e gerar um novo valor para a *sequence* até encontrar um valor único.

Esse é meu SQL:

```
select nextval('controlesequencia')as proximo,  -1 as soma
union
select currval('controlesequencia') as proximo, sum(quantidade) as soma from (
select count(*) as quantidade from manobrista where 
CAST(('0' || COALESCE(segundo_codigo,'0')) AS INTEGER) = currval('controlesequencia')
union
select count(*) as quantidade from lancamento where 
CAST(('0' || COALESCE(num_registro,'0')) AS INTEGER) = currval('controlesequencia') and data_saida = '') as mensalista
```

Quando executo no Delphi o valor retornado no `nextval` é um caractere estranho do mapa de caracteres.

```
DM.ProximoControle.FieldByName(Proximo).AsInteger;
```

Como faço para pegar o valor corretamente?

Comment: Você disse quando quando executa no delphi retorna um caracter estranho, qual é ele?
Se tentar direto no banco de dados o sql funciona normalmente?

Comment: Você poderia mostrar um pouco a mais do código? Onde você viu o caracter estranho? Foi no debug?

Comment: Diretamente no banco o sql funciona normalmente sem problema.

Comment: O Delphi não consegue converter o valor retornado para integer, quando troco para outro retorno, por exemplo, string o retorno não é um inteiro é um caracter.

Comment: //Procedimento que abre o sql, e executa a consulta apenas abre e fecha o sql

DM.GetProximoControle();
While DM.ProximoControle.eof do
begin
 if(DM.ProximoControle.FieldByName(SOMA).AsInteger =0) then 
       begin 
      unico := DM.ProximoControle.FieldByName(PROXIMO).AsInteger; 
      break; 
  end;
 DM.ProximoControle.next;
end;

Comment: Você tentou fazer um cast para bigint ? tipo: select cast(nextval('controlesequencia') as bigint) as proximo,  -1 as soma ...

Comment: Como esse código q VC postou esta funcionando se a pergunta do seu while esta eof quando deveria ser not eof ?@Priscila Almeida

Answer (score 1):

```
DM.GetProximoControle(); 
While DM.ProximoControle.eof do
 begin
   if(DM.ProximoControle.FieldByName(SOMA).AsInteger    =0) then begin  unico := DM.ProximoControle.FieldByName(PROXIMO).AsInteger; break;  
 end; 
DM.ProximoControle.next;
```

Essa rotina esta sendo executada de forma errada, pois mesmo sem fazer testes e possível perceber, que  a pergunta no `while`  esta errada porque mesmo quando temos apenas um registro e queremos iterara-lo devemos colocar `not eof` para que o bloco seja executado pelo menos uma vez.

Assim o resultado dessa rotina é inesperado.